# Access values after append in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have seen lot of question in StackOverFlow related to this topic.But none are helping in my case.

I append a table body with `bootstrap-select` and submit `button` as shown below.

```
$('#modalBodyTable').append(
                        '<tr>'+    
                            '<td>'+
                                 '<div class= " col-md-6 "><select class="bootstrap-select" name="winner">'+
                                    '<option selected disabled hidden value="">Select Winner</option>'+
                                    '<option value="'+match.player_one+'">'+match.player_one.name+'</option>'+
                                    '<option value="'+match.player_two+'">'+match.player_two.name+'</option></select>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                    '<button type="submit" id="submitWinner" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">confirm winner</button></div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>')
```

I need to access the `name="winner"` for my further action.I have tried that shown below.

```
$('body').on('click','#submitWinner',function() {
        var table=$("modalBodyTable");
        var winner=table.find('winner')
        alert(JSON.stringify(winner));
 })
```

But getting `undefined`...!!
Is there any mistake?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing the "#" in here: var table=$("modalBodyTable");

Comment: Thanks for ur response..This also not working.. `var table=$("#modalBodyTable");
        var winner=table.find('winner')` gives `{"length":0,"prevObject":{"0":{"sizzle1499977626377":{"undefined":{"parentNode":[801,9,true]}}},"length":1}}` this kind of msg.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an element like `<winner></winner>`, if you want to target the name, use the attribute selector, which will return a jQuery object containing an element, and you probably wanted the value from the select

```
$('#modalBodyTable').on('click','#submitWinner',function() {
    var table  = $("#modalBodyTable");
    var winner = table.find('[name="winner"]');
    alert( winner.val() );
});
```

```js
$('#modalBodyTable').append(
  '<tr>' +
  '<td>' +
  '<div class= " col-md-6 "><select class="bootstrap-select" name="winner">' +
  '<option selected disabled hidden value="">Select Winner</option>' +
  '<option value="player1">player 1</option>' +
  '<option value="player2">player 2</option></select>' +
  '</td>' +
  '<td>' +
  '<button type="submit" id="submitWinner" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">confirm winner</button></div>' +
  '</td>' +
  '</tr>');

$('#modalBodyTable').on('click', '#submitWinner', function() {
  var table = $("#modalBodyTable");
  var winner = table.find('[name="winner"]');
  alert(winner.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="modalBodyTable"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks at first to spend ur time for me. But here Not working.My player is an object contains name and ID.I am very new to jquery. Is it  stores object as in arry?? not able to get my object. but in APPEND function i can.but not working in event handler.Any other suggestion???